# Where do i define function for mongoose schema

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm just asking myself a question of what is the correct way of defining a function for a mongoose schema.

Lets take my `UserSchema` for example. In many of my routes i'd like to get information of the user so that i do a query `getUserByUsername` which include a `findOne(username: username)`.

As i wrote, i am doing this in many routes. So to shorten my code i'd like to have this function just one time and not inside every route again and again. I want a central place from which i can call this function whenever i want.

So i started searching and found out, that it's valid to add functions directly inside my `user.js` which is my UserSchema definition.

The whole file looks like this:

**user.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
const config = require('../config/database');

const Partner = require('./partner');
const UserRights = require('./userRights');

//User Schema - Datenbankaufbau
const UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    username: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    partnerId: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
        ref: 'Partner' 
    },
    userRights: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
        ref: 'UserRights' 
    },
    isLoggedIn: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
    },
    hasToRelog: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
    }
});



const User = module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);


// Find User by ID
module.exports.getUserById = function(id, callback) {
    User.findById(id, callback);
}

// Find User by Username
module.exports.getUserByUsername = function(username, callback) {
    const query = {username: username};
    User.findOne(query, callback);
}
```

But i now want to know, if this is a correct way of storing functions or if there is a better / other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make a controller folder in which you will define the functions,and those functions will be called in route class in making any request.You can have a detailed idea in the below article.

```
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Express_Nodejs/routes
```